# Capture RTSP with Emgu CV

Tags: c#, video-streaming, video-processing, emgucv

I have this line of code:

```
 _capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.0.61/12345");
```

It captures the rtsp stream for some seconds and then stops working. Why? If there is a work around what is it? Or if it is a bug in OpenCV?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the RtspStack used in OpenCV (I think live 555) is not sending a `GET_PARAMETER` to keep it alive in coordination with the Transport header returned from the server during the `PLAY` request.

You can manually keep it alive yourself by using another RtspClient such as the one included here..

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

And sending a `Get_parameter` every few seconds to keep the stream alive.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if its a bug in opencv, or one of the supporting libraries, then test the stream in another [rtsp client](http://www.videolan.org/) and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it in Real Player and VLC and it works. :(

Answer (score 0):

_capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.0.61/12345"); It is error

This is not user password. I have line good job

Capture = new Capture("rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.61");

Answer (score 0):

```
_capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.0.61:554");
```

***or***

```
rtsp://user:password@192.168.0.61:554/live.sdp
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This appears to be a good-faith attempt to answer the question, so I'm voting "Looks OK" on this one. I don't have the domain knowledge to know whether it's a *good* answer or not, but that's a question for voting.